# Returning Cython array

Tags: python, c++, cython, cpython

How does one properly initialize and return a Cython array? For instance:

```
cdef public double* cyTest(double[] input):
  cdef double output[3]

  for i in xrange(3):
    output[i] = input[i]**2
    print 'loop: ' + str(output[i])
  return output

cdef double* test = [1,2,3]
cdef double* results = cyTest(test)

for i in xrange(3):
  print 'return: ' + str(results[i])
```

This returns:

```
loop: 1.0->1.0
loop: 2.0->4.0
loop: 3.0->9.0
return: 1.88706086937e-299
return: 9.7051011575e+236
return: 1.88706086795e-299
```

So obviously, `results` still points only to garbage instead of the values it should point to. Admittedly, I am slightly confused with mixing the pointer and array syntax and which one is preferable/possible in a Cython context.

In the end, I want to call `cyTest` from a pure C++ function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include "cyTest.h"

void main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  initcyTest();
  double input[3] = {1,2,3};
  double* output = cyTest(input);

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << "cout: " << output[i] << std::endl;

  Py_Finalize();
}
```

This returns similar results:

```
loop: 1.0->1.0
loop: 2.0->4.0
loop: 3.0->9.0
cout: 1
cout: 6.30058e+077
cout: 6.39301e-308
```

Anyone care to explain what error I'm making? I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. It's just returning an array from Cython to C++ after all. I'll deal with dynamic memory allocation later, if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning reference to local array ( output ), which will not work.

Try changing your script to:

```
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc

cdef public double * cyTest(double[] input):
    cdef double * output = < double * >PyMem_Malloc( sizeof(double) * 3 )
    for i in xrange(3):
        output[i] = input[i]**2
        print 'loop: ' + str(output[i])
    return output
```

And in your c++ code,

after you done using `double* output` issue `free( output );`

If you want to use `cdef double* results = cyTest(test)` in your pyx script then don't forget to use `PyMem_Free(results)`

Comment: Works, but calling `free(output)` triggers a breakpoint (`Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 003D0000, 00AEBED0 )`)

Comment: Yes, that works fine (but only in Cython of course). For now I've circumvented the issue by passing a C array as argument to Cython instead of returning one.